# Path in dev server works; same path in prod server is broken

Tags: directory, pdf, customization

on my development wordpress server (using Desktop Server's "ServerPress"), one my pages has a list of pdfs; each  tag has this path: /wp-content/themes/accessgroup/docs/thePDF.pdf.

When I upload my installation to my production server, and I click on one of these links to view a pdf, I get Wordpress's default 404 page. The path to the file did not change, so how is it not seeing them? I've verified that these pdfs have indeed made it to the production server.

Even weirder -  I have another page with links of pdfs that link to the very same directory above, and I'm able to view those PDFs (although different than the ones above).

Any ideas?

UPDATE - I added a link to one of the PDFs that did not work to the actual template file for the page of PDFs, and I was able to download and view the pdf in the browser. This is pretty bizarre..same exact link...but if I click on the one added through the wp admin page editor, it doesn't work. If I click on the same one added directly to my template file, it works. What is going on?

Comment: Do the links say the same thing in the status bar when you mouse over them? (Perhaps a weird path issue or something...)

Comment: Do your PDF file names have spaces or capital characters? It's possible one server is case insensitive and the other is not.

Comment: @BrianFegter Son of a B! Yes, the live server does appear to case sensitive. The pdf was named '2012AFS.pdf', and apparently the live server cares about that. The way I have it in my anchor tag is all lower case for the name of the pdf. Thank you!!!!! I wasted a Friday night pulling my hair out, trying to figure out the problem!

Comment: :) Glad to help out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @BrianFegter comment, I was able to find and fix the problem. It was just a problem of case-sensitivity. My development environment, http://serverpress.com/products/desktopserver/ , doesn't have a problem with finding the pdf when the file name was caps and the anchor tag link was in lower case. My hosting provider seems to be the problem though, so I just changed all files to lower case and that fixed the problem.

Comment: +1 for finding the solution and answering your own question =]

Comment: For reference, Windows filesystems are case insensitive, *nix filesystems are case sensitive. hello.png and Hello.png are the same file on Windows, they're 2 different files on OS X/Linux

Comment: @TomJNowell OSX is not *necessarily* case sensitive. Depends on the file system you've chosen. In fact, I'm pretty sure that factory OSX installations use a case insensitive file system, and you have to go out of your way to change it.